# How can I concatenate two strings with a list of elements?

Tags: python

How can I concatenate two strings with a list of elements? I have this two strings and I want to add to this print a list of elements.

```
print('hi' + '-->' + ['6','5','4'])
hi ---> ['6','5','4']
```

Comment: Please add an example output!

Comment: `print('hi' + '-->' + ','.join(['6', '5', '4']))` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to print the list, you can simply pass it as an argument to `print`.

```
>>> print('hi', '-->', ['6', '5', '4'])
hi --> ['6', '5', '4']
```

If you want to do more with it than that, but the regular string representation of a list is fine, you can just call `str()` to get it:

```
>>> print('hi' + '-->' + str(['6', '5', '4']))
hi-->['6', '5', '4']
```

If you want to turn the list into a string but in a different form from the default `[..., ...]` format, `str.join` is very useful:

```
>>> print('hi' + '-->' + " ".join(['6', '5', '4']))
hi-->6 5 4
>>> print(f"hi --> [{','.join(['6', '5', '4'])}]")
hi --> [6,5,4]
```

etc

Answer (score 1):

This is an overkill, but still you can give a try to f-strings:

```
print(f"hi ---> {['6','5','4']}")
```

Using `.format()` (For python <3.6):

```
print("hi ---> {}".format(['6','5','4']))
```

Answer (score 0):

you could print it directly

```
print('hi' , '-->' , ['6','5','4'])


hi --> ['6', '5', '4']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over a list of items and print them out.

```
list = ['6','5','4']
for i in list:
   print('hi' + '-->' + i)
```

Where result will be:

```
hi-->6
hi-->5
hi-->4
```